# Magento2.3.1 IN porto theme product image on detail page not loading

Tags: error, product-images, cache, magento2.3.1

In magneto2.3.1 - I have used porto theme I notice some images not generated cache inside, I apply all commands on my live site, but not getting any error and also I apply image resize command `php bin/magento catalog:images:resize` but some images showing but rest of not loading on detail page in console getting image below error :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()  pub/media/catalog/product/cache/9d08971813a040f8f96067a40f75c615/p/m/pm0003_5.jpg
```

if anyone know regarding this type of issue facing reply me

Comment: it seems .htaccess file missing in the pub/static folder on the server.
Please get .htaccess file from fresh download and add to pub/static folder.
Check the permission of /magentorootfolder/pub/media folder. If permissions are proper, then you will have to fire php bin/magento catalog:images:resize command, from magento root folder, this command will regenerate images . Also, this process will take some time, as it will generate all images again.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check owner and group of **pub/media directory**, You may run this command from magento root directory:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R pub/media
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Assuming www-data is used as Apache user. Apache user should have permissions to a **`pub/media/catalog/product`** directory to create resized product image files.